Getting webpack_dev_server_1.default.addDevServerEntrypoints is not a function after running npm run start
I added something under "Resolutions" in my package.json file to resolve some vulnerabilities. Running npm install and npm run build works fine as expected. However after running npm run start command, I get the following error:
Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.18) is greater than your local version (12.2.17). The local Angular CLI version is used.
    
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: webpack_dev_server_1.default.addDevServerEntrypoints is not a function
  See "C:\Users\330\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-FEY8TL\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! trade-capture-ui@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the trade-capture-ui@0.0.0 start script.

I am not sure if this is a compatibility issue between webpack's dev server and my Angular version. I tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and ran npm install afterwards. It gave me no luck, I got more errors.
I am a beginner at angular and nest.js in general.
Here is my package.json file:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@rig/common": "4.4.1",
    "@rig/ng-core-components": "4.4.1",
    "@rig/ng-core-navigation": "^4.3.0",
    "@rig/pcb-web-theme": "4.1.0",
    "@rig/styles": "4.4.0",
    "colortranslator": "^1.9.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xml-formatter": "^2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "12.2.3",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "loader-utils": "^2.0.4",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.11.1",
    "html-loader": "4.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "../coverage"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.11.1",
    "loader-utils": "^2.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.5",
    "json5": "2.2.2",
    "minimatch": "3.0.5",
    "glob-parent": "6.0.2",
    "http-cache-semantics": "4.1.1",
    "webpack": "5.76.0",
    "webpack-sources": "^3.2.3",
    "ejs": "3.1.9",
    "tough-cookie": "4.1.3",
    "semver": "7.5.2",
    "escodegen": "2.1.0",
    "@babel/traverse": "7.23.2"
  }
}

